# Custom primary key breaks belongs_to parent assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, primary-key

I have a `Room` model and a `Payment` model. A payment belongs to a room.

I don't want to expose any room's `id` to the public, so I have created a `uuid` column that holds each room's custom-generated UUID. Each UUID is generated in a `before_create` hook.

Additionally, I have set

```rb
self.primary_key = 'uuid'
```

in my `Room` class. Now any calls to `find` go by the `uuid` column, and calls to `link_to room` already use the room's `uuid`. So far so good.

Unfortunately, this change seems to break how I associate a payment with a parent room. When I run

```rb
Payment.create(room: Room.first)
```

I can see that it first converts that room's UUID ("57c7bd38-71d5-4881-beb5-3427600e1c70") to an integer (57) and then assigns 57 as the `:room_id` on that payment. But there is no room with that id. The room's actual id is 2, and so the validations fail on that payment.

Changing it to use `room_id: Room.first.id` doesn't work since the `id` method (correctly) returns the `uuid`.

How do I tell it to keep using the id for relationships?

Comment: "I don't want to expose any room's id to the public". This smells like security by obscurity. There are several reasons to use UUIDs over numerical ids - just don't delude yourself that security is one of them. And please include an actual example of your models.

Comment: Why not just use a UUID primary key, which Postgres can do? Or use key encryption, which is a common practice?

Comment: @max Could be a security issue, yeah. Rooms are publicly accessible by design if one has the link, but I don't want people to be able to enumerate rooms. Hence the uuid.

Comment: Yeah but its just an illusion of safety since its defeated as soon as that link gets published somewhere.

Comment: @max I don't disagree with you there. But it does prevent people from enumerating rooms, does it not?

Comment: And there are several things that don't add up here. If you are using a numerical id as the actual primary key AND adding a UUID which is the "public" address of a model then there is no reason to monkey with `self.primary_key` or your assocations. Use the numerical PK internally and then use `Room.find_by!(uuid: params[:id])` when looking up records in the controller - or just use UUIDs all the way that are actually generated by the DB as the primary keys and foreign keys and NO numerical id.

Comment: That's just one thing but yes changing the `id` to be of type `uuid` in the db was the way to go. I was hoping to avoid having to change to `find_by!` everywhere. Put that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Changing the `id` type and NOT adding another column, that is.

Comment: @weltschmerz How did you define the associations in your models?

Comment: @spickermann As I said, payment belongs to a room. There are other associations in other models but I suppose that this is the one that matters.

Comment: So you did not configure on your associations that the foreign key should point to the uuid instead of the default id column?

Comment: I did try that using :foreign_key on belongs_to. Didn’t make a difference.

Comment: what is your Rails version? do you expect `Room.first` return first Room is ordered by id?

Comment: You never told how you foreign key is actually named. I was just guessing that you do not follow the conventions and how it might be named. But when you named the primary and the foreign key like I wrote then you would need both options plus the primary key config in the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you have simple `ActiveRecord` classes with associations like this

```
def Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end

def Payment < Application
  belongs_to :room
end
```

then Ruby on Rails makes a couple of assumptions about your database structure.

For example that the Room's primary key is stored in a column named `id` and that `Room.find` should use that column. Or that there is a column `room_id` column on the `payments` table that has the same data type as the `id` column on the `rooms` table and that matching values in these columns mean that a payment belongs to a specific room.

Ruby on Rails makes no assumptions about the data type of the foreign key column or the primary key column. That means, when you do not want to use ordinary sequential numbers as an identifier then it is totally fine to use UUIDs or any other unique value – a string or even a DateTime.

Actually, the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid-primary-keys) explain how to switch to UUID as identifiers and it needs almost no extra configuration.

But if you do not want to follow this convention and do not want to use a column named `id` as your primary key and identifier then you have to tell Ruby on Rails about that. Or you cannot follow that convention because you work, for example, with a legacy database and you do not have control over the database schema then you need to configure the non-default names at a couple of places, for example when defining the [`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to) association.

In your example you named the Room's primary identifier column `uuid` and I guess you named the foreign key `room_uuid` to match that naming schema then your classes must look like this:

```
def Room < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'uuid'

  has_many :payments, foreign_key: 'room_uuid', primary_key: 'uuid'
end

def Payment < Application
  belongs_to :room, foreign_key: 'room_uuid', primary_key: 'uuid'
end
```

Comment: I don't think it should be `user_uuid` but `room_uuid`, right? Also, are you sure I need the `foreign_key` and `primary_key` in *both* models?

Comment: Of course, it should be `room_uuid`, I fixed it. Yes, you would need the options on both sides of the association because both sides are independent of each other and both introduce new methods on each model and therefore need to be aware of the non-default configuration.

Comment: And, just to confirm, it needs to have the `primary_key` thing in the `has_many :payments` call even though payments don't have a uuid but just a regular old id? It reads a bit like it would expect the payment model to have a uuid column as well...

Comment: Yes, because that option is not about the primary key of the model itself but it is about the primary key that is used for methods like `payment.create_room` on the association.